# error : MSB4803: The task "ResolveComReference" is not supported on the .NET Core version of MSBuild

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, raspberry-pi, visual-studio-2017

I have made a project in VS2019. I have the same project in .NET Core and .NET Framework. I use a COM reference in my project. I would like to migrate these projects to Pi4.
A simple Hello World project (.NET Core) is running successfully on the Pi4 machine. However, when I try to run my project (.NET core or .NET Framework) it does not run on the Pi4. It says COM is not supported.

I tried to build the project using MSBuild in my Windows environment after looking for solutions in Google. I also see a similar error here. The error is:  error : MSB4803: The task "ResolveComReference" is not supported on the .NET Core version of MSBuild. Please use the .NET Framework version of MSBuild.

The .NET Framework project also gives a similar error.
error MSB4028: The "ResolveComReference" task's outputs could not be retrieved from the "ResolvedFiles" parameter. Object does not match target type.

Does anyone have similar issues?

Comment: COM is not available on any Unix flavors, you can't use that library.

Comment: @Hans. It seems your statement is true. Thank you.

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/resolvecomreference-task?view=vs-2019#msb4803-error

Comment: @jdweng, Can you explain me how to invoke MSBuild.exe.  I did not understand this sentence .  Try building the project by invoking MSBuild.exe from the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt, since this uses the .NET Framework version of MSBuild. I was giving the command dotnet publish at the developercommand promt. Which command I should give?

Comment: Use the -detailedSummary option which will give everything and then you can find what is actually causing the error.

Comment: I gave the command MSBuild.exe at the developer command promt for my project. And it build successfully. However later if I say dotnet publish it is still showing the same error. I should only do MSBuild.exe and then use them for linux platform?. Will it work?.

Comment: It seems I can only build the project. I can not migrate to Linux environment.

Comment: If you really need COM on the Raspberry PI, you could try Windows 10 embedded -- I don't know if COM is available there or not, but the development environment was really solid when I last used it (a few years ago now) -- but yeah, you literally just hit F5 in your desktop instance of Visual Studio, and poof, it's running on the Raspberry PI -- you can even debug it while it's running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues/3986

According to the above link. The employee of Microsoft is saying they can not give solution in the near future.

Comment: Of course not, you are talking about using COM components on Linux, this will never happen without a virtual machine.

Answer (score 3):

Set the Projects to x86 for them to build the Interop, the Interop created still could not be used in x64 runtimes.

Add the COM Reference to the Core project, Build it and you will get an Interop.YourCom in the bin/x86/core/debug folder.

Remove the COM reference, and re-add the Interop, it will be put into the Assemblies Dependencies, and MSBuild will work.

My MSB4803 was from a WIXInstaller project, for ADOX, and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao

Comment: Won't work on Linux, so what's the point of using .net core?

Comment: @Isma do you expect to be able to use a COM library on linux?

Comment: Nope, that wouldnt be possible (well, maybe it could be done using wine or virtualization), I was just pointing out that using .net core with the com reference would be not so useful, but actually with .net 5 it could be done.

Comment: Nothing COM works on Linux with out wine or virtualization. 
Also the OP made a .NET FW version of the system that had the same problem, for him it's across OS even if they're pushing to a PI.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this question many times and I experienced the same several times in different projects. It doesn't matter if it is Visual Studio 2019 or 2022 and the version of the build, unless you are working with the old MSBuild in a legacy environment, the COM Reference doesn't work. It is always safe to build it in the command line to understand if anything in the VS environment works. I don't truly understand why Microsoft let you make those references in the Visual Studio environment when they will not work nearly anywhere else.

There are some workarounds that might or might not work but if your code is already pointing at a COM library there is no much to do. You can install the NuGet package which is going to pass the build stage and remove the COM reference.

`Install-Package Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel -Version 15.0.4795.1001`

The NuGet package has some differences at the types level that you will need to fix (the COM reference allows you to get specific types instead of objects from the cells values)

In any case, you will need the COM installed in the server, there is no workaround that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say I like this error message or the link it shows on how to fix it, to be polite.... ;-);

I figured it out and thought as there are a lot of answers that are not helpful to share mine. What I did is update your command to force the use of msbuild.

```
dotnet msbuild -v:normal "FullOrRelativePathTo\MyProject.csproj" -p:Configuration=RELEASE
```

If that fails, try:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" "PathTo\Project.csproj" /p:Configuration=RELEASE
```

Answer (score -1):

I know I'm late to the party, but here is a workaround working for me when I want to use Office Interop in .NET (Core):

1. Create an empty .net Console app (I'm using Rider and .NET 7)
2. Build it with the default MSBuild (17.0 in my case at the time of writing)
3. Add Interop references to the project file (I don't use Nuget, only generate these in a dummy .NET Framework project while adding COM references to Office libraries), eg.

   ```
   <ItemGroup>
       <COMReference Include="Excel">
           <Guid>{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}</Guid>
           <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
           <VersionMinor>9</VersionMinor>
           <Lcid>0</Lcid>
           <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
           <Isolated>False</Isolated>
           <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
           </COMReference>
   </ItemGroup>
   ```
4. Change the solution MSBuild version to 4.0
5. Try to build the solution, but the project will not even load properly due to an outdated MSBuild version
6. Revert the MSBuild version to the default one
7. Build the project - success! (this is the magic part, I can't explain it :P)

Comment: I am struggling with the same problem, right now... so, you are not late at all :)

Comment: @YevheniyTymchishin, is this solution working for you? :)

Comment: my problem is a bit different... I need to build a solution using command line. I was using "dotnet build" before I added ComReference. So, my solution is to use "msbuild" instead "dotnet build".

Answer (score -1):

**From terminal:**

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel --version 15.0.4795.1001
```