# Release Build Fails on Docker Publish MSB4803

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, blazor, .net-6.0

I am trying to publish a .NET Core 6 Blazor Server project to Portainer. I can build and run the project fine in Debug, however when I try Release or to publish the project the build fails giving me the following.

> error MSB4803: The task "ResolveComReference" is not supported on the
> .NET Core version of MSBuild. Please use the .NET Framework version of
> MSBuild. See https://aka.ms/msbuild/MSB4803 for further details.
> [/src/Necon/Necon.csproj]

The output of the entire build attempt is:

```
------
 > [build 7/7] RUN dotnet build "Necon.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build:
#15 2.489   All projects are up-to-date for restore.
#15 3.000 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.408/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2927,5): error MSB4803: The task "ResolveComReference" is not supported on the .NET Core version of MSBuild. Please use the .NET Framework version of MSBuild. See https://aka.ms/msbuild/MSB4803 for further details. [/src/Necon/Necon.csproj]
#15 3.007 
#15 3.007 Build FAILED.
#15 3.007 
#15 3.007 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.408/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2927,5): error MSB4803: The task "ResolveComReference" is not supported on the .NET Core version of MSBuild. Please use the .NET Framework version of MSBuild. See https://aka.ms/msbuild/MSB4803 for further details. [/src/Necon/Necon.csproj]
#15 3.007     0 Warning(s)
#15 3.007     1 Error(s)
#15 3.007 
#15 3.007 Time Elapsed 00:00:01.90
------
WARNING: buildx: git was not found in the system. Current commit information was not captured by the build
Dockerfile:14
```

Most of my googling brings me to this answer [error : MSB4803: The task "ResolveComReference" is not supported on the .NET Core version of MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62577989/error-msb4803-the-task-resolvecomreference-is-not-supported-on-the-net-cor) however it nearly 3 years old. I have also tried [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/895702/error-msb4803-the-task-resolvecomreference-is-not) with no success.

My docker file is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Necon/Necon.csproj", "Necon/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Necon/Necon.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Necon"
RUN dotnet build "Necon.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Necon.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Necon.dll"]
```

Mr Necon.csproj is:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>8ac9eb75-ec3e-42b0-b702-405a8e375b34</UserSecretsId>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <EnableSdkContainerSupport>true</EnableSdkContainerSupport>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <COMReference Include="DecklinkPublicLib">
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
      <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
      <Guid>1469d378-8829-4ff0-9b3b-07dd5b16f3cb</Guid>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <Isolated>false</Isolated>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </COMReference>
    <COMReference Include="BMDSwitcherAPI">
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
      <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
      <Guid>8a92b919-156c-4d61-94ef-03f9be4004b0</Guid>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <Isolated>false</Isolated>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </COMReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate" Version="6.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.13">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="6.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="MudBlazor" Version="6.1.8" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

My dockerignore file is:

```
**/.classpath
**/.dockerignore
**/.env
**/.git
**/.gitignore
**/.project
**/.settings
**/.toolstarget
**/.vs
**/.vscode
**/*.*proj.user
**/*.dbmdl
**/*.jfm
**/azds.yaml
**/bin
**/charts
**/docker-compose*
**/Dockerfile*
**/node_modules
**/npm-debug.log
**/obj
**/secrets.dev.yaml
**/values.dev.yaml
LICENSE
README.md
```

My publish settings are:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue related to below COMReference, I have researched, and `DecklinkPublicLib` seems can be used in linux, but  `BMDSwitcherAPI` can't.

So you can comment it in your .csproj file and give it a try.

**Tips**
After you comment it, you need to try to complie it in your local, then deploy it.

**Workaround**

Using windows-platform, not linux.

```
 <COMReference Include="DecklinkPublicLib">
  <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
  <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
  <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
  <Guid>1469d378-8829-4ff0-9b3b-07dd5b16f3cb</Guid>
  <Lcid>0</Lcid>
  <Isolated>false</Isolated>
  <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
</COMReference>
<COMReference Include="BMDSwitcherAPI">
  <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
  <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
  <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
  <Guid>8a92b919-156c-4d61-94ef-03f9be4004b0</Guid>
  <Lcid>0</Lcid>
  <Isolated>false</Isolated>
  <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
</COMReference>
```

Comment: That has worked, thank you. I tried removing these references earlier but still had issues, I must've stuffed it up in that instance.